# How do I write a general user input statement to be used multiple times with different values?

Tags: java, user-input

I'm new to Java so I didn't really know how to word my question. I am trying to write a text adventure with lots of different options for the user to input. I have progressed quite far but am getting very confused with all the user inputs and options for them to take. Notice I created a short way of entering System.out.println before **main** that allows me to just enter *text* instead. I am wondering if I can do something similar with the user input block of code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AdventureTest {

static void text(String body){
System.out.println("" + body);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    char direction;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Go: (n/e/s/w)? ");
    direction = input.nextLine().charAt(0);

    switch( direction )
    {
        case 'n':
            text("You go North");
            break;
        case 'e':   
            text("You go East");
            break;
        case 's':
            text("You go South");
            break;
        case 'w':
            text("You go West");
            break;
        default:
            text("You fall down a hole!");
    System.exit(0);
    }

    text("Program continues");
}
```

}

Comment: The common way is to ask multiple choice-questions without individual answers. So the user has only predefined options that you can identify by numbers or prefixed numbers like answer_01, answer_02, ...

Comment: If you want to have multiple inputs from the user, the easiest thing to do would be to put it in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is your solution my man!
I put your switch in a do...while loop, so after every user choice you can ask him/her if they want to choose another step, and it perfectly run after the user doesn't want to continue.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AdventureTest {

private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

private static void text(String body) {
    System.out.println("" + body);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char direction,answer = 0;
    do{
    System.out.print("Go n,e,s or w?: ");
    direction = input.nextLine().charAt(0);


        switch( direction )
        {
            case 'n': {
                text("You go North");
                System.out.println("Do you want to continue? (y/n)");
                answer = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
            }
            break;
            case 'e': {
                text("You go East");
                System.out.println("Do you want to continue? (y/n)");
                answer = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
            }
            break;
            case 's':{
                text("You go South");
                System.out.println("Do you want to continue? (y/n)");
                answer = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
            }
            break;
            case 'w':{
                text("You go West");
                System.out.println("Do you want to continue? (y/n)");
                answer = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
            }
            break;
            default:
                text("You fall down a hole!");
                System.exit(0);
        }
    }while(answer == 'y');
    text("Program continues");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood properly. Do you want a shorcut for reading input?
I thing, the most generic way to handle diferent inputs from a central function, is to return a string and then convert it to the type you need like this:

```
public static String read(){
    return (new Scanner(System.in)).nextLine();
}
```

But I dont recommend you to do that as you are creating a new Scanner every time you read user input.
You could also create versions for this for every type you need like in this situation.

```
public static String readChr(){
    return (new Scanner(System.in)).nextLine().charAt(0);
}
```

But you would end up making the wheel again.
Please clarify me what you meant.

Comment: Thanks, I meant like if user inputs "n" for North, do I need to rewrite the whole Scanner statement again and switch statement again to continue with what lies to the North and the user options from there.

Comment: What will happen if, having gone to the North on a previous move, we again decide to go further to the North on the next? Or to the East, instead? And then the North again after that? There's virtually no way you'll be able to write enough `switch`es to cover every possibility once the world gets beyond a couple of squares from the starting point!  You'll need to think about building a map of the world and keeping track of where the player has wandered.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is *loop*, asking the same question, but then you will need some way to stop looping.

Here I have put in a [`do .. while (condition)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loop.
I create a boolean `done` which starts as `false` -- you are not "done".
When `q` is entered instead of a nesw direction, `done` is set to `true` so the while condition changes and the program stops looping.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AdventureTest {

    static void text(String body) {
        System.out.println("" + body);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char direction;
        boolean done = false;    //  <----- Added This
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter q to quit");

        do {
            System.out.print("Go: (n/e/s/w)? ");
            direction = input.nextLine().charAt(0);

            switch( direction )
            {
                case 'n':
                    text("You go North");
                    break;
                case 'e':   
                    text("You go East");
                    break;
                case 's':
                    text("You go South");
                    break;
                case 'w':
                    text("You go West");
                    break;
                case 'q':            // <---- new case, for quit
                    text("You have quit");
                    done = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    text("You fall down a hole!");
                    System.exit(0);
            }

            if (!done) text("Program continues");
        }
        while (!done);
    }
}
```